# Automatically add PHPDoc using existing comments

Tags: phpdoc

I want to tidy a large function include file where PHPDoc is only used partially. there are some functions without PHPDoc like

```
function name($var1,$var2){ // explanation what it does
  # ...
}
```

and some where the PHPDoc exists but is incomplete like some variables missing:

```
/**
  * explanation
  *
  * @param boolean $var1 foo foo foo
  *
  * @return null
  */
function name2($var1,$var2){ 
  # ...
}
```

or just

```
/** explanation
  */
function name3($var1,$var2){ 
  # ...
}
```

How is it possible to add all missing variable definitions and return values, using a correct "unknown" tag for the ones added?

It could analyse each function if it has a return value and it should convert the already existing comments (behind each function) and use them in PHPDoc.

I am aware that you will have to check the result manually, but it would be really helpful to generate a skeleton with the data that already exists.

Comment: which framework or CMS you are using ? Or Core php ?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using a combination of [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php), [token_get_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) which uses Zend's lexical scanner to parse a string into PHP [lanugage tokens](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) and quite possibly regular expressions.

The problem with Reflection is that some methods, like `ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getReturnType` are available only on PHP 7.

In PHP 5+ you can use `ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getParameters`, `ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getDocComment` etc.

If there's no DocBlock you could get the function start and end lines with `ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getStartLine` and `ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getEndLine`, copy the source block to a string and use `token_get_all` to obtain an array of PHP tokens to analyze individually.

Reflection example in PHP 5.6:

```
<?php

/**
 * explanation
 *
 * @param boolean $var1 foo foo foo
 *
 * @return null
 */
 function test($var1, $var2) {

 }

 echo ReflectionFunction::export('test', true);
```

Output:

```
/**
 * explanation
 *
 * @param boolean $var1 foo foo foo
 *
 * @return null
 */
Function [ <user> function test ] {
  @@ index.php 10 - 12

  - Parameters [2] {
    Parameter #0 [ <required> $var1 ]
    Parameter #1 [ <required> $var2 ]
  }
}
```

Comment: That sounds a lot of work. I rather thought about parsing the php file through `awk` and retrieve the comments and variable names this way

Comment: @rubo77 Yes, without full Reflection it's hard. But `awk` won't help you with return types either.

Comment: It would help already to have a solution with just a dummy return value

Comment: this is not a solution, just a hint how to solve it with a lot of work. But since this is the only answer, and it probably **would** work if you invest several days of programming time, I will give the bonus here in 20 h, if there won't come up an easyer solution ;)

Comment: @rubo77 Unfortunately the real solution involves a very large number of monkeys typing randomly on an equally large number of keyboards :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can be helpful for you.

As I am using **sublime text** editor. I installed **DocBlockr**.
Here is [link](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs)

Comment: that helps a bit  (like in eclipse), but you still have to type `/**` and ENTER to get a PHPDoc Block with the right amount of lines and you can jump with TAB to the next variable.And you have to add this fix: https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs/issues/334

Comment: You should add my comment to your answer, otherwise it is only half the solution

Comment: @rubo77 : I think you did you checked issue date that is : Dec 10, 2014 by sameg14. After that many commit has been done on github. I tryed, i did not found this issue.

Comment: I have the issue still thats what i meant. On Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Exception are always. :) But as i know editor is just IDE. it does not matter which OS you are using. Sublime Text is available for almost all OS's. If you are facing still this issue. It might be your sublime text plugins are not updated OR you are using two plugins for PHPDocs.